# Play video in modal box pop up

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, flowplayer

I have a flowplayer library . Now i want when i click on a link my all the videos should be list in the modal box popup. I tried everything but its not working. I am not able to figure out what actually wrong with this.

When i load the videos without popup its working fine but when i tried to load it into the pop up. Its nothing displayed. Please help me anyone. Below is javascript code...

```js
function show_samples(artist_id, language){
    $("#sample-box").load("<?php echo SITE_PATH?>index.php?rt=artist/show_vo_samples", {'artist_id':artist_id, 'language':language} , function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            $('#sample-box').modal();
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../libraries/video_player/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<div id="sample-box" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="../libraries/video_player/flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.4167">
            <video>
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://edge.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4">
            </video>
          </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show_samples(artist_id, language){
    $("#sample-box").load("<?php echo SITE_PATH?>index.php?rt=artist/show_vo_samples", {'artist_id':artist_id, 'language':language} , function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt == "success")
            $('#sample-box').modal();
        if(statusTxt == "error")
            alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/js/flowplayer-3.2.12.min.js">
</script>


<div id="sample-box" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="flowplayer" data-swf="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf" data-ratio="0.4167">
            <video controls loop autoplay>
         
          <source type="video/mp4" src="https://edge.flowplayer.org/bauhaus.mp4">           
       
            </video>
          </div>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Hi Tarang what the changes you are making. Please explain?

Comment: .Thanks mate..Yes now its working fine. I think you adding  "controls loop autoplay" . But i don't  want to make video auto play because there are a list of 4 to 5 videos in the popup

Comment: 'autoplay' remove